# django-import-export error while importing data into database

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-import-export

[image: Here's the SS of import error]

[image: And this is the SS of CSV file]

```
    Line number: 1 - 'id'
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/home/carlmark/Desktop/Final/realtyredefine/env/lib/python3.6/site- 
    packages/import_export/resources.py", line 500, in import_row
    instance, new = self.get_or_init_instance(instance_loader, row)
    File "/home/carlmark/Desktop/Final/realtyredefine/env/lib/python3.6/site- 
    packages/import_export/resources.py", line 277, in get_or_init_instance
    instance = self.get_instance(instance_loader, row)
    File "/home/carlmark/Desktop/Final/realtyredefine/env/lib/python3.6/site- 
    packages/import_export/resources.py", line 266, in get_instance
    self.fields[f] for f in self.get_import_id_fields()
    File "/home/carlmark/Desktop/Final/realtyredefine/env/lib/python3.6/site- 
    packages/import_export/resources.py", line 266, in <listcomp>
    self.fields[f] for f in self.get_import_id_fields()
    KeyError: 'id'
```

```
models.py

class PropertyModel(models.Model):
    Created_By = models.ForeignKey(User, default=1, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    Created_Date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    Serial_No = models.IntegerField()
    Property_ID = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=15)
    Last_Updated_By = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    Last_Updated_On = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    Hot = models.BooleanField(null=True, blank=True, default=False)
    Shared_Website = models.BooleanField(null=True, blank=True, default=False)
    MCG_Property_Code = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    File_Name = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    Picture_Attached = models.ImageField(upload_to='images', null=True, blank=True)
    # Project_info
    Land_Use = models.CharField(max_length=25, choices=land_choice, null=True, blank=True)
    Construction_Completion_Date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    Project_Structure = models.CharField(max_length=25, choices=structure_choice, null=True, blank=True)
    Project_ID = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    Project_Name = models.CharField(max_length=25, null=True, blank=True)
    Possession_Status = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=possession_choice)
    Total_Plot_Area = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True, blank=True)
    Unit_Plot_Area = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True, choices=unit_choice)
    Plot_No = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True, blank=True)
    Total_Floor = models.CharField(max_length=2, null=True, blank=True)
    # Property Info
    Property_Status = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=prop_status_choice)
    Property_For = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=prop_for_choice)
    Calling_Update = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True, choices=calling_choice)
    Property_Type = models.CharField(max_length=15, choices=prop_type_choice)
    Property_Sub_Type = models.CharField(max_length=25, choices=prop_sub_type_choice)
    Property_Use = models.TextField()
    # Address
    Full_Address = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    Building_Name = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    Wing = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    Unit_No = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    Floor = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    Block = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    Landmark = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    # All Locality
    All_Locality = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    Road = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    Colony = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    Locality_1 = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    Locality_2 = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    Sector = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=sector_choice, null=True, blank=True)
    Area = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    City = models.CharField(max_length=15, choices=city_choioce)
    State = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=state_choice)
    Country = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=country_choice)
    Pin_Code = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    # Owner Details
    Owner_ID = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    Owner_Full_Name = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    Owner_All_Contact = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    Owner_Source_Type = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True, choices=owner_source_choice)
    Owner_Company_Name = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    Owner_Name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    Owner_Mobile = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    Owner_Home_Landline = models.CharField(max_length=15, null=True, blank=True)
    Owner_Office_Landline = models.CharField(max_length=15, null=True, blank=True)
    Owner_Alternative_No1 = models.CharField(max_length=15, null=True, blank=True)
    Owner_Alternative_No2 = models.CharField(max_length=15, null=True, blank=True)
    Owner_Alternative_No3 = models.CharField(max_length=15, null=True, blank=True)
    Owner_Email = models.EmailField(null=True, blank=True)
    Owner_Address = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    Owner_Representative_Name = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    Owner_Representative_No = models.CharField(max_length=15, null=True, blank=True)
    Owner_Caretaker_Name = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    Owner_Caretaker_No = models.CharField(max_length=15, null=True, blank=True)
    Co_Owner_Name = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    Co_Owner_No = models.CharField(max_length=15, null=True, blank=True)
    Owner_Comment = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    # Area
    Super_Area_Min = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True, blank=True)
    Super_Area_Max = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    Unit_Area = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=unit_choice)
    Maintainance_Charge_PSF = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True, blank=True)
    Maintainance_Charge_Min_Rs = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True, blank=True)
    Maintainance_Charge_Max_Rs = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True, blank=True)
    Efficiency = models.CharField(max_length=3, null=True, blank=True)
    Covered_Area_Min = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True, blank=True)
    Covered_Area_Max = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True, blank=True)
    Expected_Rent_PSF = models.IntegerField()
    Expected_Rent_Min_Rs = models.IntegerField()
    Expected_Rent_Max_Rs = models.IntegerField()
    For_Sale = models.BooleanField(null=True, blank=True, default=False)
    Sale_Price_PSF = models.IntegerField()
    Sale_Price_Min_Rs = models.IntegerField()
    Sale_Price_Max_Rs = models.IntegerField()
    # Aminities
    All_Aminities = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    Aminities_1 = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    Aminities_2 = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    Aminities_3 = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    Aminities_4 = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    Aminities_5 = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    Aminities_6 = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    Aminities_7 = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    # Property Details
    Vastu = models.CharField(max_length=15, null=True, blank=True, choices=vastu_choice)
    Furnishing_Type = models.CharField(max_length=25, choices=furn_type_choice, null=True, blank=True)
    Furnishing_Quality = models.CharField(max_length=15, null=True, blank=True, choices=furn_quality_choice)
    Property_Available = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=prop_avail_choice, null=True, blank=True)
    Property_Remarks_Internal = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    Property_Remarks_External = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    # Furnishing Details
    Furnishing_Detail = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    Property_Condition = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    Cabin_No = models.CharField(max_length=3, null=True, blank=True)
    Workstation_No = models.CharField(max_length=5, null=True, blank=True)
    Car_Parking_No = models.CharField(max_length=3, null=True, blank=True)
    Conference_No = models.CharField(max_length=3, null=True, blank=True)
    Pantry = models.CharField(max_length=3, null=True, blank=True)
    Server_Room = models.CharField(max_length=3, null=True, blank=True)
    Meeting_Room = models.CharField(max_length=3, null=True, blank=True)
    Cubical = models.CharField(max_length=3, null=True, blank=True)
    Keys_With = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    # eXtra
    Internal_Comments = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    External_Comments = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    Assigned_Manger = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=manager_choice)
    Group = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=group_choice)
    Teams = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=team_choice)
    Source_Channel = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=source_channel_choice)
    Sub_Source_Channel = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=sub_source_choice)
    # Pre-rented
    Pre_Rented = models.BooleanField(null=True, blank=True, default=False)
    Company_Name = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    Pre_Rented_Area_Min = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True, blank=True)
    Pre_Rented_Area_Max = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True, blank=True)
    ROI = models.CharField(max_length=3)
    Sale_Price_Pre_Rented_PSF = models.IntegerField()
    Sale_Price_Pre_Rented_Min_Rs = models.IntegerField()
    Sale_Price_Pre_Rented_Max_Rs = models.IntegerField()
    Sale_Remark = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    # Lease Terms
    Lease_Start = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    Possession_Date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    Lease_Period = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    Security_Deposit = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    Lock_in_Period = models.CharField(max_length=3)
    Monthly_Rent_Min_Rs = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True, blank=True)
    Monthly_Rent_Max_Rs = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True, blank=True)
    Rent_Escalation = models.CharField(max_length=3)
    Pre_Rented_Remark = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    # Remaining
    Extra1 = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    Extra2 = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    Extra3 = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    Extra4 = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    Attachement = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    Video_Link = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)

    objects = PropertyManager()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Properties"
        ordering = ['-Created_Date']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Property_ID
```

```
admini.py

@admin.register(PropertyModel)
class PropertyAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['Property_ID', 'Created_By', 'Last_Updated_By']
```

I'm trying to import data from a CSV file to my Django database but whenever I tried to import I got "KeyError: 'id'" although there's no "id" field in my model. I'm this issue only when I using PostgreSQL, there's no error when I import the same data in sqlite3.

Comment: We need to see your code and import file. At minimum, `models.py`, and the first 2 rows of your csv file. Please edit your answer to include these.

Comment: @GregKaleka I've uploaded the screenshots, please have a look

Comment: OK. Please also include your `models.py` code, and your `admin.py` code (as text, not as screenshots - see the sidebar as you're editing for how to format python code).

Comment: @GregKaleka I've uploaded both as you said. Sorry for the bad database, as I'm new to Django, there are soo many things that I've to learn.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem.
It is that for import django import-export uses **"id"** by default.
First, create a **resources.py** file - where you will declare settings for import and export. And as an exception, declare **"id"**.

resources.py

```
from import_export import resources
from .models import *

class PropertyAdminResource(resources.ModelResource):

    class Meta:
        model   =   PropertyModel
        exclude = ('id',)
```

admin.py

```
from .resources import *

@admin.register(PropertyModel)
class PropertyAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    resource_class  =   PropertyAdminResource
    list_display = ['Property_ID', 'Created_By', 'Last_Updated_By']
```

I highly recommend using resources.py - where you can modify the methods for import and export.

Comment: This solution works and it should be marked as the valid one.

Comment: Doesn't work for me, still getting same error, using 2.4.0

Comment: @mariodev same, did you solve it by any chance?

Comment: @AjayChaurasia I did, my problem was that the pk was pointing to different field then "id", so I added `import_id_fields = ('id_field_name', )` to Meta's resource class. This solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

you need to let the resources model know your primary key, if it didn't find it will automatically set it to 'id'

here is an example

### models.py

```
class Product(models.Model):
  my_id =  models.CharField(max_length=255, primary_key=True)
```

### admin.py

```
from import_export.admin import ImportExportModelAdmin
from import_export import resources

class ProductAdminResource(resources.ModelResource):
    class Meta:
         model = Product
         import_id_fields = ['my_id']

@admin.register(Product)
class ProductAdminView(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    resource_class = ProductAdminResource
```

Answer (score 0):

I had some errors like you and managed to solve them following this answer - https://github.com/django-import-export/django-import-export/issues/92#issuecomment-598009569

I changed from version 2.0.2 to 2.0.1, removed the custom primary key and migrated again

I hope this helps with your problem

Comment: Apparently, the versions are higher than this, and still not working

Answer (score 0):

Please read
https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html#customize-resource-options

So for your your model you could do

```
class PropertyAdminResource(resources.ModelResource):
            

    class Meta:
        model = PropertyModel
        
        import_id_fields = ('Property_ID',)
        
class PropertyModelAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    resource_class = PropertyAdminResource
        
        
admin.site.register(PropertyModel, PropertyModelAdmin)
```

tested with **django-import-export 2.7.0**