# Incorrect csv format when using ImportExportModelAdmin

Tags: django, django-models

I'm trying to upload the csv file below but it's only uploading some columns and then some of those values are empty. Prior to this, I was receiving a error:

````
```  self.fields[f] for f in self.get_import_id_fields()
KeyError: 'id'```
````

which I fixed by using advice from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60492050/django-import-export-error-while-importing-data-into-database)  basically saying django import-export uses "id" by default. So, create a resources.py file - where  I declare settings for import and export. And as an exception, declare "id" in the resouse.py file, which is what I did and the upload worked... BUT now it's incorrect format.

## Part of the CSV

```
Customer ID,Customer Name,Latitude,Longitude,town,region,country
C00001,Valentino Solomon,57.13514,-2.11731,Aberdeen,Aberdeen City,Scotland
C00002,Luna Armstrong,57.13875,-2.09089,Aberdeen,Aberdeen City,Scotland
C00003,Jaylen Crane,57.101,-2.1106,Aberdeen,Aberdeen City,Scotland
C00004,Christopher Fritz,57.10801,-2.23776,Milltimber,Aberdeen City,Scotland
```

## Customer Model

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    customer_id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=150)
    customer_name = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=True)
    Latitude= models.FloatField(null=True)
    longitude= models.FloatField(null=True)
    town = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=True)
    region = models.CharField(max_length=150,null=True)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=True)
```

## Admin.py file:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from systemx.models import Customer, Demand, Product
from import_export.admin import ImportExportModelAdmin
from systemx.resources import *


class DataImportExportAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    resource_class  =   PropertyAdminResource
    ist_display = ['customer_id', 'customer_name', 'latitude', 'longitude', 'town', 'region', 'country']

# class DataImportExportAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
#     list_display = ['customer_id', 'customer_name', 'latitude', 'longitude', 'town', 'region', 'country']

admin.site.register(Customer, DataImportExportAdmin)
```

## Resources.py file:

```
from import_export import resources
from .models import Customer

class PropertyAdminResource(resources.ModelResource):

    class Meta:
        model = Customer
        # exclude = ('id',)
        import_id_fields = ('customer_id',)
```

Can anyone see where i'm messing up?

Thanks!

Screenshot of admin table after import:
[image: wrong data import]

Comment: You don't need the line `exclude = ('id',)` because `customer_id` is the pk. The `import_id_fields = ('customer_id',)` line is enough. That being said, I'd double check that my longitude and latitudes are being imported correctly because the order might matter.

Comment: @Scratch'N'Purr thanks for noticing that! Unfortunately, it still uploads the csv file as in the screenshot :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I see now. The reason why the values aren't populating the columns is because your CSV file has the column names with spaces instead of underscores. You have 2 options:

1. (Quick and easy) Change the CSV column names to reflect the attribute names defined in your model. E.g. `Customer ID` would become `customer_id` and `Customer Name` would be `customer_name`.

   You probably also want to lowercase your `Latitude` and `Longitude` column names.
2. (Requires some extra code) Manually define the column name in your resource by mapping the attribute of the model to the column in the CSV. E.g.:

   ```py
   from import_export.fields import Field

   class PropertyAdminResource(resources.ModelResource):

       customer_id = Field(
           attribute="customer_id",
           column_name="Customer ID",
       )
       customer_name = Field(
           attribute="customer_name",
           column_name="Customer Name"
       )

       class Meta:
           model = Customer
           fields = (
               'customer_id',
               'customer_name',
               'latitude',
               'longitude',
               'town',
               'region',
               'country',
           )
           import_id_fields = ('customer_id',)
   ```

Comment: HI dude thanks for your comment it worked! What I also did was use the code I originally had and changed the headers within the CSV to match the fields I specified in the resources.py file: ```customer_id,customer_name,latitude,longitude,town,region,country
C00001,Valentino Solomon,57.13514,-2.11731,Aberdeen,Aberdeen City,Scotland
C00002,Luna Armstrong,57.13875,-2.09089,Aberdeen,Aberdeen City,Scotland
C00003,Jaylen Crane,57.101,-2.1106,Aberdeen,Aberdeen City,Scotland
C00004,Christopher Fritz,57.10801,-2.23776,Milltimber,Aberdeen City,Scotland```